# Webapi CreateErrorResponse throws ArgumentException

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to call to the extension method CreateErrorResponse with a status code and string.

The problem that the function throws ArgumentException with additional information that the value dose not fall within the expected range.

I tried to send different values of arguments, explicitly cast the arguments and using different overloads.

## Code

```
private HttpResponseException GetItemsException(IEnumerable<Guid> ids, string errorMessage, HttpStatusCode status)
{
    HttpResponseMessage error = Request.CreateErrorResponse(status, errorMessage);
    error.Headers.Add("ids", ids.Select(id => id.ToString()));

    return new HttpResponseException(error);
}
```

Comment: Show some code. It will help others better understand you problem

Comment: The problem was that because this function is called in another thread, the request thread is finished his run and there is no request.